# Illegal mix of collations for operation for date/time comparison

Tags: mysql

I get this error

> Illegal mix of collations for operation <=

for the following WHERE clause:

```
time(table1.dt1)<=date_add(table1.tim,interval 60 second)
```

`dt1 = datetime`, `tim = time`

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Wild guess: is it because of the collations on `dt1` and `tim` being different?

Comment: Not the case :) they are `DATETIME` and `DATE` respectively. Doesn't `COLLATION` apply to text fields only ? Anyway, I did try to set them both to `utf8_general_ci` (they obviously didn't set as they are not `strings`) - same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As explained in the manual entry for [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

   > The return value depends on the arguments:
   >
   > - [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) if the first argument is a [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) (or [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)) value, or if the first argument is a [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) and the unit value uses `HOURS`, `MINUTES`, or `SECONDS`.
   > - String otherwise.

   In your case, because `table1.tim` is a `TIME` value, the function is returning a string.

   The string is returned in the character set and collation given by [`character_set_connection`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection) and [`collation_connection`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection).
2. As explained in the manual entry for [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time):

   > Extracts the time part of the time or datetime expression ***`expr`*** and returns it as a string.

   The string is returned as a binary string (why not using the connection character set & collation is beyond me—perhaps a bug?).
3. As explained in the manual entry for [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html):

   > If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.

   Therefore the comparison undertaken is a string comparison, but the `binary` string cannot be coerced to a suitable collation for comparison (as its encoding is not known).  Hence the error you are witnessing.

One could force the comparison to be conducted correctly by explicitly [casting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html) one or both of the operands, but I'd be tempted just to rework the clause so that conversion takes place implicitly from comparison against a `TIME` type:

```
TIME(table1.dt1 - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) <= table1.tim
```