# Yet another count/rank for consecutive events in the last 'n' days in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble in to setup a query to count/rank the consecutive days an event had happened in the last '*n*' days. I.e: If an event had happened consecutively '*k*' times in the last '*n*' days, with no gaps in relation to the reference date.

Visually (0 means no event, and 1 means an event) from current date to the past '*n*' days:

```
case A - 01111 (count as 0 since there's no event in the previous date).
case B - 11001 (count as 2 consecutive days)
case C - 11110 (count as 4 consecutive days)
case D - 00110 (also count as 0)
case E - 10111 (count as 1)... and so on
```

Considering a 'pseudo' structure:

```
Table1
uid
eventid

table2
eventid
datetime
```

What I need as result is a 'rank' of uid wich has consecutive events in the last n days so if I got these values on Table1 and Table2:

```
Table1
(1, 100)
(1, 101)
(1, 102)
(1, 103)
(2, 104)
(2, 105)
(2, 106)

Table2
(100, '2015-09-11 00:00:00')
(101, '2015-09-10 00:00:00')
(102, '2015-09-09 00:00:00')
(103, '2015-09-07 00:00:00')
(104, '2015-09-11 00:00:00')
(105, '2015-09-10 00:00:00')
(106, '2015-09-05 00:00:00')
```

The result shoud be:

```
uid - consecutive
1 - 3
2 - 2
```

That means uid 1 has events 100, 101, and 102 consecutively in the last days but eventid 103 is out because it is not consecutive.

I've looking for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230015/how-to-group-by-consecutive-data-date-in-this-case) and tried to apply some of them, but none consider the consecutive days based on a reference (current) date.

The near I've come is to make a left join using the date for each case something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (uid) WHERE date(datetime)=curdate()-interval 3 day) 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (uid) WHERE date(datetime)=curdate()-interval 2 day)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (uid) WHERE date(datetime)=curdate()-interval 1 day)
```

Also my knowledge in using var inside SQL are almost none, and if possible I'd like to avoid using procedures, making a single call from inside php to mysql.

Thx

Comment: I've found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230015/how-to-group-by-consecutive-data-date-in-this-case) wich is pretty near to what I need (especially on [Cyril-gandon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/128662/cyril-gandon) answer, but unfornatelly I've no means to adjust it... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter variable to do just that.

First we'll get a table with `uid` and `datetime` columns, ordered properly:

```
SELECT `uid`,`datetime` FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`eventid`=`table2`.`eventid`
ORDER BY `uid`, `datetime`
```

Now we'll use that as a subquery, advancing a counter each time the `uid` is the same as last row, and the `datetime` is 1 day ahead of the last row's date. Here's how it's done:

```
SET @counter = 1;
SET @lastDate = '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
set @lastUid = 0;

SELECT
  `uid`,
  IF (((DATE_ADD(@lastDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)=`datetime`) AND (`uid`=@lastUid)),
    @counter := @counter+1, @counter := 1),
  (@lastUid := `uid`),
  (@lastDate := `datetime`),
  @counter as `counter`
FROM (
  SELECT `uid`,`datetime` FROM `table1`
  INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`eventid`=`table2`.`eventid`
  ORDER BY `uid`, `datetime` ASC
  ) `uidDateTable`
```

Now all we have left to do is to use that query as a subquery and find the `MAX` value of `counter` per `uid`. So that's the actual query you need:

```
SET @counter = 1;
SET @lastDate = '2010-01-01 00:00:00';
set @lastUid = 0;

SELECT `uid`, max(`counter`)
FROM (
  SELECT
    `uid`,
    IF (((DATE_ADD(@lastDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)=`datetime`) AND (`uid`=@lastUid)),
      @counter := @counter+1, @counter := 1),
    (@lastUid := `uid`),
    (@lastDate := `datetime`),
    @counter as `counter`
  FROM (
    SELECT `uid`,`datetime` FROM `table1`
    INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`eventid`=`table2`.`eventid`
    ORDER BY `uid`, `datetime` ASC
    ) `uidDateTable`
  ) `uidCounters`
GROUP BY `uid`;
```

Comment: Just for futher reference, if you get an error of [illegal mix of collations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052254/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-for-date-time-comparison) in mysql try to format the `DATE_ADD` as `DATE` and everything goes fine... `... IF (((DATE(DATE_ADD(@latDate ... `

Comment: Sorry, but yes. this SQL do not bring the *last* consecutive events but consecutive events in the last n days. So it 'fails' on 'case D' above, for example. To solve this issue I've changed the approach to solve this in the algorithm (php) since there's seem no reason to force SQL to do all the work that an algorithm should.